# Calculating timestamp difference and avg in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a `timestamp` column in a table `commits`. I'm trying to get the difference between the earliest timestamp and the latest one in weesks. Then I need to find the average number of commits per week per user.

In the table, I have the following columns.

`id` | `repo` | `author_email`  | `author_name` | `author_date` | `lines_total`

I've managed to write the following query:

```
select repo, author_name, author_email, COUNT(author_email) AS COMMITS, SUM(lines_total) AS LINES, MIN(author_date) AS FIRST_COMMIT,
MAX(author_date) AS LAST_COMMIT, TIMESTAMPDIFF(week, MAX(author_date), MIN(author_date)) AS WEEKS
from commits 
where repo='apache.camel'
group by repo, author_name, author_email, author_email 
order by COUNT(author_email) DESC;
```

But the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is not working. If I remove it, everything else works well. I'm not sure how I can get the difference and the avg.

Error:

> ERROR: column "week" does not exist SQL state: 42703 Character: 182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

week needs quotes.

```
select repo, author_name, author_email, COUNT(author_email) AS COMMITS, SUM(lines_total) AS LINES, MIN(author_date) AS FIRST_COMMIT,
MAX(author_date) AS LAST_COMMIT, TIMESTAMPDIFF('week', MAX(author_date), MIN(author_date)) AS WEEKS
from commits 
where repo='apache.camel'
group by repo, author_name, author_email, author_email 
order by COUNT(author_email) DESC;
```

you also need a function called timestampdiff that handles weeks in the way you want (ISO week? nearset/lesser/greater multiple of 7 days ?)
mysql has somethign called timestampdiff but there is no indication of what it considers to be a week. fractions are aparrently rounded towards zero.

```
select repo, author_name, author_email, COUNT(author_email) AS COMMITS, SUM(lines_total) AS LINES, MIN(author_date) AS FIRST_COMMIT,
MAX(author_date) AS LAST_COMMIT
, ( MAX(author_date)::date- MIN(author_date)::date )/7 AS WEEKS
from commits 
where repo='apache.camel'
group by repo, author_name, author_email, author_email 
order by COUNT(author_email) DESC;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error here: function timestampdiff(unknown, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
SQL state: 42883

Comment: yeah, there's no such function. what is it supposed to do?

Comment: needs to find out the difference between the earliest date and the latest date. (MAX(author_date), MIN(author_date))

Comment: which sort of week do you want?

Comment: i didn't get your question

Comment: mysql's behaviour is undocumented.

Comment: use that floor thing instead.

Comment: So the floor one determines the total number of weeks between the dates. Right?

Comment: it counts the number of midnights between the two timestamps and divides the result by 7, I took floor out, it's not needed.